# Ms access database has skipped an auto increment number (ID) after repare. How to restore it?

Tags: ms-access, auto-increment

I have Microsoft access database. I have about 1200 records, with attached documents through forms and am generating several reports with it.

While doing data entry access just halted and I restarted. Then it said repair is required and automatically started repairing. After it loaded everything except a few records. I happened to find one record being omitted from the auto generated ID. Now the problem is, I cannot skip this ID. I cannot issue new ID. So how do I fill in the gap?

This error was shown:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0x4D.png)

Here is the Skipped record Autoincrement ID snippet
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ4D8.png)

Comment: Change the field from AutoNumber to Long, insert record, change the field back. But you are facing a design issue: Autonumbers are not meant to be meaningful; their _single_ purpose is to identify the record. If you need a number series of any kind, design you own number generator.

Comment: Good! Thanks for the suggestion, but when I try to change the field type error message shows, that "You can't change the data type or field size; it is part of one or more relationships " so this means i have to disconnect all the relations? it would be a real problem, as they'are several and diffrent one to one and one to many etc.

Comment: Can use INSERT action SQL to create record then run Compact & Repair to reset the autonumber seed.

Comment: After compact and repair, now it is showing, Stop all macros, messege, that shows "Enable all macros" and enable button is inactive, and only disable button is Active, so now my autoload form is not showing. So now i am thinking transferring data to either new access database or any other application. i will definately not be using the autoincrement as staff id. But any suggestion where should i transfer? that is more rely able? if i will be having a few thousands of records? for network shareable standalone DB for PC?